# Check disk image file system type

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-image

How could I check the file system format of a disk image?

I know that I can check with the `file` command but I would like to automate the behaviour.

```
$ file img.raw
img.raw:   data

$ file img.ext4
img.raw:   Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=346712e7-1a56-442b-a5bb-90ba4c6cc663 (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)

$ file img.vfat
img.vfat:  DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 16, reserved sectors 16, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 256, sectors/track 32, heads 64, sectors 1024000 (volumes > 32 MB) , serial number 0x4b5e9a12, unlabeled, FAT (16 bit)
```

I would like to check if the given image disk is formatted with the given format.

For example `checkfs <image> <format>` returns 0 if the image contains a 'format' file system, another value otherwise.

I thought about doing something like `file <image> | grep <format>` and check the return code, however for vfat filesystems, 'vfat' is not appearing on `file`'s output.

I could also write a script to do it but I can't find tools which allow me to get the file system format of a disk image.

I've also tried with the following tools: `fdisk`, `parted`, and `df`.

**Is there a tool which would allow me to check a disk image file system format and that works with most used file system formats?**

Comment: So what was wrong with `parted`?

Comment: There is no option to get file system type with `parted`. So I have to print the full partition table and then parse output using `sed` or `awk`. I think there are better solutions

Comment: It has a machine parsable output mode if you wanted to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found what I needed

- `blkid -o value -s TYPE <image>` will return the fs type or nothing if it's raw data.

***EDIT:***

As mentioned by @psusi, `parted` has a machine parsable output. I find it less convenient than using `blkid` but it could also be useful.

- `parted -m <image> print | tail -n +3 | awk -F ":" '{print $(NF-2)}'` will print the fs type of each partition.

`tail -n +3` is used to skip the two first lines 
`awk -F ":" '{print $(NF-2)}'` is used to get the fs type which is the third last element starting from the end